# Angular Slick adding text caption

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm learning to add some custom taglines for each slides using the angular slick https://www.npmjs.com/package/angularslick

How should i scope the text data onto each of the active slides itself?

```
<body ng-controller="MainController">
    <div class="col-md-9">           
      <slick autoplay="true" autoplaySpeed="500" fade="true" dots="true">
        <div ng-repeat="image in images">
          <img data-lazy="{{image}}">
          <div ng-repeat"caption in captions"></div>
        </div>
      </slick>
    </div>
</body>
```

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['slick']);
app.controller('MainController', function($scope) {
  $scope.images = [
    "images/slider-banner1.png",
    "images/slider-banner2.png",
    ];

  $scope.captions = [
    "tagline for banner1",
    "tagline for banner2",
  ];
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just bind the data to a single array that contain both the image `src` an `caption` like so

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['slick']);
app.controller('MainController', function($scope) {
  $scope.images = [
    {
      src: "images/slider-banner1.png",
      caption: "tagline for banner1"
    },{
      src: "images/slider-banner2.png",
      caption: "tagline for banner2",
    ];
})
```

and now you can just `ng-repeat` the `$scope.images` like so:

```
<body ng-controller="MainController">
    <div class="col-md-9">           
      <slick autoplay="true" autoplaySpeed="500" fade="true" dots="true">
        <div ng-repeat="image in images">
          <img data-lazy="{{image.src}}">
          <span>{{image.caption}}</span>
        </div>
      </slick>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <slick autoplay="true" autoplaySpeed="500" fade="true" dots="true">
    <figure ng-repeat="image in images">
     <img data-lazy="{{image}}">
  <figcaption ng-repeat"caption in captions">{{caption}}</figcaption>
</figure>
      </slick>
```

That`s the answer in your way and the better approach can be seen in this pen

[Pen for Slick](http://codepen.io/pegsbenedict/pen/ByQYJY/)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<body ng-controller="MainController">
<div class="col-md-9">           
  <slick autoplay="true" autoplaySpeed="500" fade="true" dots="true">
    <div ng-repeat="image in images">
      <img data-lazy="{{image}}">
      <div ng-bind="captions[$index]"></div>
    </div>
  </slick>
</div>
```